# how do i split a text into segments based on wherever a period OR a newline appears?

Tags: python

My text is:

```
'3. COMMENCEMENT; TERM OF LEASE; AND OPTION TO RENEW\nThe initial term of this Lease shall be for a period of Five (5) years commencing on'
```

I want the following list:

```
[
    '3. COMMENCEMENT; TERM OF LEASE; AND OPTION TO RENEW',
    'The initial term of this Lease shall be for a period of Five (5) years commencing on'
]
```

Comment: Why isn't it being split on the first period? (The one after 3)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh should it be? It looks like OP just wants to split on `\n`

Comment: @C.Nivs Their title suggests otherwise.

Comment: Then I suppose some clarification *is* needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> initial_statement = "3. COMMENCEMENT; TERM OF LEASE; AND OPTION TO RENEW\nThe initial term of this Lease shall be for a period of Five (5) years commencing on"
>>> temp_list = initial_statement.split("\n")
>>> print(temp_list)
['3. COMMENCEMENT; TERM OF LEASE; AND OPTION TO RENEW', 'The initial term of this Lease shall be for a period of Five (5) years commencing on.']
```

Or make it a string again

```
>>> final_result = ""
>>> for i in temp_list:
...     final_result += i
... 
>>> print(final_result)
3. COMMENCEMENT; TERM OF LEASE; AND OPTION TO RENEWThe initial term of this Lease shall be for a period of Five (5) years commencing on.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace all instances of a `.` with a `\n`, then you can split at every `\n`, and get the output you want.

```
text = '3. COMMENCEMENT; TERM OF LEASE; AND OPTION TO RENEW\nThe initial term of this Lease shall be for a period of Five (5) years commencing on'

# You might wish to replace the "." with a ".\n" instead so the "." is preserved
text = text.replace(".","\n")

text = text.split("\n")

print(text)
```

Output:

```
['3', ' COMMENCEMENT; TERM OF LEASE; AND OPTION TO RENEW', 'The initial term of this Lease shall be for a period of Five (5) years commencing on']
```